# ASP.Net MVC Poor Production Performance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

We have a MVC 3 application which has been deployed onto a newly built Windows 2008 R2 Web Edition server which is performing badly.

This application has been through development, quality assurance and user acceptance testing cycles on the same operating system (different boxes) with no performance issues.

The only difference we can see with the server is that it sits in the DMZ and as such has two network adapters configured, one for the internet, and one to punch through the firewall.

We have put all sorts of logging into the application and confirmed that up until the 'return ActionResult' everything is working correctly (ie ~500ms). It then takes 15 seconds to render the page.

We have tried turning on debug=false in the config file, i'm not sure what else to look for here, it seems like an environment issue.

Any suggestions please ? I am about to investigate if the thread pool size could be causing problems.

Also, if it helps the page is using multiple partial views, i have read others having problems with them.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Are you deferring query execution or are you making sure that queries complete before your action returns? Even though your action is returning you could still be experiencing delays due to the database if your query execution leaks into your views.

Comment: Did you run a profiler against the database to see what queries are generated and how it manages?

Answer (score 1):

Since the application performs ok in other environments I would suggest you investigate following:

1. **Database** - are you running against different database? How long the queries execute? If you have non-optimized database with million records on production, and only few records in test you want find performance problems soon enough.
2. **Network** - what is the latency between web box and database? If you loose 100ms for each database query just because of network than if your page triggers 50 queries you've lost 5secs. I've seen poorly configured routers / load balancers that were doing just that.

Try profiling each component of your system (db, network, web box) in order to find out where you're wasting all that time. Try http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/.

PS. You MUST have `debug=false` in your prod env.

Comment: Thanks Jakub, we have ruled out any issues with network or database, this is something happening on the individual server itself. Currently we are looking at Kerberos authentication timeouts as a possible problem.